# Will this processor be compatible with my PC?

Tags: cpu

I have an Advent T9508 PC with a Foxconn 45CM motherboard. The processor that the computer came with when we purchased it many years ago was a Core 2 Duo @ 2.2 GHz. I found a Core 2 Duo 3 GHz E8400 processor for just £15 on Amazon, a bargain. I was wandering if

```
a) The processor will be compatible (same number of pins/correct socket type) 

b) If the current heatsink would work fine with the new processor, or if I would have to use a new aftermarket heatsink? 

c) The processor is a 64 bit, whereas the old processor is 32 bit (including a 32 bit windows) will it still work correctly?
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your old processor is 64-bit as well. There are no 32-bit Core 2 Duo processors.

But let’s start from the beginning. Yes, both your motherboard and the CPU you want to buy fit Socket 775. But your motherboard does not support this CPU. The compatibility list can be found [here](http://www.foxconnchannel.com/ProductDetail.aspx?T=motherboard&U=en-us0000316) (Tech Support → Type “Support List” → Search → CPU Support List). That being said, it *might* work. On the other hand, your PC may simply refuse to boot.

I’d recommend always getting a better cooling solution, because virtually everything you can buy is better and quieter than the stock solution.

Comment: `your motherboard does not support this CPU` - there might be something I'm missing here but according to the link the processor `Core™2 Duo` is listed as one of the supported ones, and the processor I am looking to purchase is also a `Core™2 Duo`. I might be completely wrong though?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I double checked on the tech support think and you are correct. Thank you.